# how to be able to have my next and previous button with colorbox?

Tags: colorbox

So here his the web site in question [creyation.ca](http://creyation.ca)...
I want to be able to the browse the image (when enlarged) with a next and previous button,
relative to same group of thumbs of course.

Comment: since i have tried almost everything, for some code ask me a specific area . please :P

Answer (score 0):

I like [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/howto), It can do exactly what I believe you are looking for, with minimal code, setup instructions are at the link I provided

Here are some [demos](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples)